# What is the proper way to read a non element value in the custom JQuery validation rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

What must be instead of **element.data('maxLength')**? 

My target is to check the value without the spaces. That is what I need. 
So, standart maxLength is unsuitable for me.

```
$.validator.addMethod("numberLength", function(value, element) {
   return value.replaceAll(' ', '').length <= element.data('maxLength');
}, '-');
...
price: {
    numberlength: 12
}
```

Comment: You do not need to write a custom method to retrieve the `maxlength` attribute.  The plugin automatically sets rules based on the HTML 5 attributes.  If that's not what you're doing, then please explain, because there are already rules in place that look at the length of the data input... like the `maxlength` rule, and `max` that will ensure numerical input does not exceed a value.

Comment: @Sparky, sorry, I will use replace all space instead of trim. My target is to check the value without the spaces. That is what I need. So, standart maxLength is unsuitable for me.

Comment: So why not look at the `maxlength` (notice the lower-case "L") inside the plugin to see how it's done.  Then use a version of that within your custom method.

Comment: Again, what is `element.data('maxLength')` supposed to represent?

Comment: @Sparky, thx! The answer is e.maxlength.

Comment: `e.maxlength` is simply retrieving the `maxlength` HTML 5 attribute from the input element.  Since the code in your OP is using `"element"` as the argument name, it would be `element.maxlength`.  This is what I was asking you about in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `maxlength` method from within the plugin...

```
maxlength: function( value, element, param ) {
    var length = $.isArray( value ) ? value.length : this.getLength( value, element );
    return this.optional( element ) || length <= param;
}
```

Create your custom method based on the default function...

```
$.validator.addMethod("numberLength", function( value, element, param ) {
    var trimmedvalue = value.replaceAll(' ', '');
    var length = $.isArray( trimmedvalue ) ? trimmedvalue.length : this.getLength( trimmedvalue, element );
    return this.optional( element ) || length <= param;
}, '-');
```

Comment: Or like this `$.validator.addMethod("numberLength", function(value, e) {
    return value.replaceAll(' ', '').length <= e.maxlength;
}, '-');`.

Comment: @ArthurKharkivskiy, the argument name representing `"element"` is completely arbitrary.   `function(value, e) { return value.replaceAll(' ', '').length <= e.maxlength; }, '-'); ` **is exactly the same as** `function(value, element) { return value.replaceAll(' ', '').length <= element.maxlength; }, '-');`  **or** `function(value, foo) { return value.replaceAll(' ', '').length <= foo.maxlength; }, '-');`